# Angularjs: Can I have my directive run after controller API callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

first time asker. Apologies if my jargon isn't quite right I'm new to angularjs

I have a `controller` which gets a list of products with a HTTP call

```
contractManagementControllers.controller('PriceBandsCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',     '$http', '$location',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $location)
    {
        $http.get('products').success(function (products)
        {
            $scope.productList = products
        })
    }
```

And a `directive` which I would like to have access to that product list.

```
contractManagementControllers.directive("priceBands",function($http)
{
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: 'true',
        templateUrl: 'Partials/PriceBand.html',
        link: function ($scope, ele, attrs, c)
        {
            // use $scope.productList
        }
});
```

My issue is with the order in which things happen.  The controller function runs first, followed by the directive link function, followed by the callback which sets the product list.  As such `$scope.productList` is undefined in the directive link function and gives an error

Is there a way to force the link function to wait until the callback has completed?

Answer (score 1):

Set default value to `productList` in order not get error about undefined variable

```
contractManagementControllers.controller('PriceBandsCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',     '$http', '$location',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $location)
    {
        $scope.productList = [];
        $http.get('products').success(function (products)
        {
            $scope.productList = products
        })
    }
```

and then watch for changes of the `productList` in directive:

```
contractManagementControllers.directive("priceBands",function($http)
{
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: 'true',
        templateUrl: 'Partials/PriceBand.html',
        link: function ($scope, ele, attrs, c)
        {
            $scope.watch('productList', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                //Perform here if you need
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: That's great thanks, although turns out the watch needs a dollar sign
$scope.$watch

Answer (score 0):

no need of waiting for `callback` in `angularjs`. just put the `$scope.productList=[];` in your `controller as first line`. it will not give undefined to directive.

In your directive `link function` just write the `$watch` function to watch changes in element.